# WatchKit: Paging only for groups or a single area of the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I would like to use the pages function only for one area (group) of the screen. Is this possible?

The label "Test" should not move, when moving over to the screen "2":

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just put the label on each page.

Comment: The label gets scrolled too then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to create a fixed interface element across controllers in the current version of WatchKit. Each `WKInterfaceController` instance always takes up the full screen.